# Fecho a conexao, e nao consigo mais conexao NodeJS Mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js

Preciso fechar as conexões apos a consulta retornar sucesso ou erro, a primeira vez que faco a consulta ok, mas depois ele fecha e nao consulta mais...
Já tentei fechar em várias partes do código sem sucesso.

```
    try {
        connection.query(sql, [empresaID], (error, results) => {
            if (error) return res.status(400).json(error);

            if (results.length === 0) {
                res.status(401).json({ msg: 'Empresa não encontrada' })
                //connection.end()
            } else {
                res.status(200).json(results);
                //connection.end()
            }
            //connection.end()
        })
    } catch(err) {
        res.status(500).json(err);
    }
```

Comment: poderia explicar melhor? não consegui compreender o problema

Comment: Dependendo da forma que você está pegando essa conexão não é necessário usar o `end` após usar a `query`

Comment: nesse meu caso preciso fechar a conexao para que não exceda o limite de conexões simultaneas no banco?

Comment: nesse meu caso preciso fechar a conexao para que não exceda o limite de conexões simultaneas no banco?

Answer (score 2):

O seu código está com o fluxo errado, porque funciona assim, se der algum `error` não tem `results` e se tem `results` não tem `error` precisa colocar um `if` para tomar essa decisão, seguindo o seu exemplo:

```
try {
    connection.query(sql, [empresaID], (error, results) => {
        if (error) {
            return res.status(400).json(error);
        } else {
           res.status(200).json(results);               
        }
        connection.end()
    })
} catch(err) {
    res.status(500).json(err);
}
```

ou seja, esse código acima foi só para entender o fluxo que deve ser feito. Se se o `empresaID` não existe não dá erro também é retornado um valor padrão que pode ser melhor trabalhado nesse `if`.

Uma outra coisa, a conexão deve ser criado sempre que vai utilizar e fechada após a sua utilização, eu criaria uma `js` assim:

```
const mysql = require('mysql');

module.exports = {
    connection: function () {
        return mysql.createConnection({
            host     : 'localhost',
            port     : 3306,
            user     : 'root',
            password : '',
            database : ''
        });
    },    
    executeSQLQueryParams: function (sql, params, callback) {
        const conn = this.connection();
        conn.query(sql,params, (error, results, fields) => {        
            callback(error, results, fields);
            conn.end();
        });       
    },    
    executeSQLQuery: function (sql, callback) {
        const conn = this.connection();    
        conn.query(sql, (error, results, fields) => {
            callback(error, results, fields);
            conn.end();
        });    
    }
}
```

Depois no local que vai utilizar a conexão importe:

```
const conn = require('./mysql-connection');
```

e utilize assim:

```
conn.executeSQLQuery('SELECT * FROM todos', (error, results, fields) => {
    if (error) {
        res.json(error);
    } else {
        res.json(results);
    }
});
```

não vai se preocupar mais com esse problema, porque com relatei essa `connection` deve sempre ser criada nas funções.

Comment: {
  "code": "PROTOCOL_ENQUEUE_AFTER_QUIT",
  "fatal": false
}

Comment: {
  "code": "PROTOCOL_ENQUEUE_AFTER_QUIT",
  "fatal": false
}

Comment: Quando inicio o servidor a primeira requisição faz normal exibe os resultados, mas depois da esse erro abaixo,

Comment: Quando inicio o servidor a primeira requisição faz normal exibe os resultados, mas depois da esse erro abaixo,{
  "code": "PROTOCOL_ENQUEUE_AFTER_QUIT",
  "fatal": false
}

Comment: Quando inicio o servidor a primeira requisição faz normal exibe os resultados, mas depois da esse erro abaixo,
  "code": "PROTOCOL_ENQUEUE_AFTER_QUIT",
  "fatal": false

Comment: Quando inicio o servidor a primeira requisição faz normal exibe os resultados, mas depois da o erro abaixo

Comment: @StewartCintra precisamos ver o código inteiro desse servidor?

Comment: @StewartCintra você poderia colocar aonde dá o erro e como está montando seu arquivo que inicia esse serviço?

Comment: @StewartCintra eu já imagino como seja , você criou alguma função que retorne a conexão ... precisa ser assim!

Comment: Eu tenho um problema parecido, quando está sendo muito usado, eu recebo o erro de que já muitas conexões abertas, mas eu uso o banco de dados dinâmico, então preciso a cada vez, abrir nova conexão. Eu faço o conn.close mas parece que não fecha.

Comment: @Nebenzahl conexões simultâneas precisa verificar isso no servidor de banco.